# Android EditText: Smooth expanding animation when new line is started

Tags: java, android, kotlin, animation, android-edittext

I have noticed that Telegram has a smooth animation in their chat EditText when a new line is inserted / started.

Below I have two GIFs. The first is Telegram, the second is my app.

[image: Telegram EditText]

[image: My EditText]

---

How can you achieve such an animation effect?

I tried to google it, but I didn't find anything. I know Telegram is open source, I tried to find out from their GitHub, but I couldn't find what gives the EditText this smooth animation.

Comment: It looks like they have a complete custom content view and they draw everything themselves and they have implemented a custom animation with the Animator APIs.

Take a look at [ChatActivity](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TelegramOrg/Telegram-Android/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/ChatActivity.java) and the `checkAnimation` method.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy. I too added it in my chat app and it works like a charm. In your root layout, add this line:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

This will animate all the changes happening in the layout.

#### Edit

If that does not help, you can do this.

```
userIdInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)  {

           ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(edMESSAGE.getHeight() - 40, edMESSAGE.getHeight() + 40)
                        .setDuration(500);
                anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        edMESSAGE.getLayoutParams().height = (int)animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        edMESSAGE.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
                anim.start();

            }
            return false;

        }

    });
```

You can call this method in `onKeyListener` and when the new line key is pressed, this code can be called.

#### Edit

Sometimes, while entering the text, it goes to new line. For animation this, we can do this:

```
chatInputET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String string = s.toString();
    if (string.length() > 0 && string.charAt(string.length() - 1) == '\n') {
      ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(edMESSAGE.getHeight() - 40, edMESSAGE.getHeight() + 40)
                        .setDuration(500);
                anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        edMESSAGE.getLayoutParams().height = (int)animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        edMESSAGE.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
                anim.start();
    }
  }
});
```

And for the backspace key, you can do this:

```
inputMessage.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            String string = inputMessage.getText().toString();
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && (string.length() > 0 && string.charAt(string.length() - 1))  {

           ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(edMESSAGE.getHeight() + 40, edMESSAGE.getHeight() - 40)
                        .setDuration(500);
                anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        edMESSAGE.getLayoutParams().height = (int)animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        edMESSAGE.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
                anim.start();

            }
            return false;

        }

    });
```

Comment: Adding this doesn't change something for me. I have the EditText wrapped in a LinearLayout and added `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to that LinearLayout. It doesn't add the animation.

Comment: I will check. I don't know why. it worked for me

Comment: I have edited the answer. please look into it

Comment: How do I notice a new line being started? `KEYCODE_ENTER` isn't enough when a line is filled and a new one is started automatically. Also, this is missing the flip side, when a new line is removed and the EditText must shrink.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer does not work, you can use this:

```
binding.message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            int linesCount = 0;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().length() == 0){
                    binding.message.getLayoutParams().height = defEditTextHeight;
                    linesCount = binding.message.getLineCount();
                    return;
                }
                if (linesCount == 0){
                    linesCount = binding.message.getLineCount();
                    binding.message.getLayoutParams().height = defEditTextHeight;
                    return;
                }
                if (linesCount < binding.message.getLineCount()) {
                    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(binding.message.getHeight(), binding.message.getHeight() + 60)
                            .setDuration(250);
                    anim.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
                        binding.message.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        binding.message.requestLayout();
                    });
                    anim.start();
                }else if( linesCount > binding.message.getLineCount()){
                    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(binding.message.getHeight(), binding.message.getHeight() - 60)
                            .setDuration(250);
                    anim.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
                        binding.message.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        binding.message.requestLayout();
                    });
                    anim.start();
                }
                linesCount = binding.message.getLineCount();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Where `defEditTextHeight` is the default height of the edit text fetched like this:

```
defEditTextHeight = binding.message.getHeight();
```

Hope It helps